# Django/DRF: Is it ok to make validate methods static?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, static-methods

In an effort to make my code as clean as possible, I'm making a pass to add @staticmethod to all methods that don't use `self`. In DRF, a typical validate method looks like this:

```
    def validate_website(self, value):
        value = value.strip()
        if len(value) > 200:
            raise ValidationError(_('Website may have up to 200 characters.'))
        return value
```

In other words, validate methods almost always use `value` instead of `self`, so they are candidates for being @staticmethod. In addition to wanting to eliminate the annoying squiggly underscores my IDE puts under the method name to let me know it "might be static", I'm thinking that there is surely *some* overhead associated with passing `self` to each method. So eliminating that overhead if not needed can't be a bad thing, right?

So, two questions... 1) Is it ok to add @staticmethod to those validate methods?; and, 2) Is it worth it from a performance perspective?

Comment: 1) It is fine to make these methods static so long as they never need to access the instance 2) the performance impact is completely negligible